# Fitting of moving average process

Tags: time-series, arima, moving-average

I have been trying to wrap my head about the parameters estimation and forecasting of moving average model.

It appears that the fitting use the innovations algorithm. If I understood correctly you assume your optimal linear predictor has the form

$\hat{X}_{n+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \theta_{n,j} (X_{n+1-j} - \hat{X}_{n+1-j}) $

with $\hat{X}_1 = 0$

One then estimate these parameters iteratively using the innovations algorithm:

$$\theta_{n,j} = [\gamma(j)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-j} \theta_{n-j,k} \theta_{n,j+k} v_{n-j-k}] / v_{n-j}$$
$$v_n = \gamma(0)-\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_{n,j}^2 v_{n-j}$$
with $$v_0 = \gamma(0)$$.

Okay, now let's consider a MA(1) process :

$$X_n = Z_n + \theta Z_{n-1}$$

with $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

We can compute the autocorrelation function of this process :

$$\gamma(0) = (1+\theta^2) \cdot \sigma^2$$
$$\gamma(1) = \theta \cdot \sigma^2$$

Now, if we apply the first iteration of the innovations algorithm, we'll find:

$$\theta_{1,1} = \gamma(1) / \gamma(0)$$
$$v_1 = \gamma(0) - \frac{\gamma(1)^2}{\gamma(0)}$$

What's making me crazy is that obviously $\theta_{1,1} \neq \theta$ and $v_1 \neq \sigma^2$.

Yet, it seems that we could very well infer the parameter $\theta$ and $\sigma$ by solving for them in the autocorrelation functions.

My question is then the following : why don't we solve the autocorrelation equations to estimate the parameters of the model and then use this to compute the innovations ? It seems we are using $\gamma$'s already, so why not directly infering our best estimate of $\theta$ ?

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Hi: I didn't through the whole thing but $\gamma_{1} = \theta \sigma^2$. Maybe that helps ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. My question still stands :)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're question is ?  I don't think it's generally what is used in practice ( i.e. in software ) but you can use the innovations algorithm to  estimate the parameters of the MA process which in this case are $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$. The $\hat{\theta}$ also happens to be an estimate of the first order autocorrelation which is $\frac{\gamma(1)}{\gamma(0)}$ so it makes sense that that is the estimate of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Basically I'm wondering why one would use the innovations algorithm instead of inferring $\theta$ and $\sigma$ by matching the moments. But you seem to suggest that it is not really use in practice. I now found that most software packages would use a Kalman filter representation of the process and just do maximum likelihood.

Comment: Hi Edward: yes. KF and maximum likelihood is a popular approach. Not that I know so much but  I had never heard of the innovations process for estimation until you mentioned it. There's some package in R that has it but it's not a package that's been around that long. I forget the name but I saw it earlier when googling for innovations process. TSIM maybe ?

Comment: I was kind of close but that only helps in horseshoes. https://rdrr.io/cran/itsmr/man/ia.html